# Why not Use Yum for Adding Repos Instead of Importing Keys, then RPM etc?

Tags: centos, rpm, yum

Whenever I want to install a repo, the standard instructions are to import a public key with "rpm --import" , then rpm "-Uvh" for the actual rpm file. Like for the ELRepo here: http://elrepo.org/tiki/tiki-index.php

However, why can't I just use yum to install the rpm file? So basically instead of:

```
rpm --import https://www.elrepo.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-elrepo.org
rpm -Uvh http://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-3.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm
```

I just type:

```
yum install http://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-3.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm
```

And everything works fine! It's much nicer to use yum, since it's easy to keep track of what I've installed (or even better - dnf!), remove things etc. Surely that's what a package manager is for right? Why use the rpm command at all?

Comment: You should understand that `yum` (or `dnf`) sits on top of `rpm` and effectively does those commands for you. But if the RPM isn't in a repo, or the machine isn't online, being able to fall back to the `rpm` commands is a useful skill. Additionally, *in theory*, a distribution could use RPM files without a higher-level front end. RPM was started by Red Hat but is now [supposedly independent](http://rpm.org/about.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. And, yes, you can install the package using yum. No problem. And if you did not imported gpg key previously, then yum will ask you.